# Kalman Filter Going crazy after around 1200 iterations

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, tracking, kalman-filter

I am using the OpenCV C++ implementation of the Kalman Filter with the constant acceleration model in x and y direction. The filter works pretty well up until around 1200 frames and then it start giving very extreme predictions.

Following graph shows the the prediction vs the measurement for both x and y coordinates and you can clearly see where it goes wrong.

[image: Position x from Frame 1050]

[image: Position y from Frame 1050]

And this is the code that runs every frame:

```cpp
TrackingResult KalmanFilter::Process(TrackingInput& input)
{
    cv::Mat prediction = _kalmanFilter.predict();
    Point2 predictPt(prediction.at<float>(0), prediction.at<float>(1));
    cv::Mat_<float> measurement(2, 1, CV_32F);

    if (input.DetectionResult.FoundBall)
    {
        measurement(0) = input.DetectionResult.BallPosition.x;
        measurement(1) = input.DetectionResult.BallPosition.y;

        cv::Mat estimated = _kalmanFilter.correct(measurement);
        _ballPosition = Point2(estimated.at<float>(0), estimated.at<float>(1));

        return TrackingResult(_ballPosition, predictPt, input);
    }
    else
    {
        return TrackingResult(predictPt, predictPt, input);
    }
}
```

The code is inspired by OpenCV's official Kalman Filter example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d70/samples_2cpp_2kalman_8cpp-example.html#a13). I initialized the transition matrix correctly by assuming the constant acceleration model. More info on this model can be found [here](https://www.kalmanfilter.net/multiExamples.html)

I tried passing constant values as measurements and it stayed very stable so I'm not entirely sure what the issue here really is. The issue can not be with the video too because I am using the camera to test it.

I can not create an MCVE because I'd have to give 1200 frame positions to reproduce it but you can visualize the values I pass in the graphs above.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: *so I'm not entirely sure what the issue here really is.* -- The default answer to your question is "have you debugged your code?"  What happens if you observe at iteration 1200 or whereabouts the values being used/calulated/etc.?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's how I got the above figures. The detection (measurement) remains pretty much stable but the predictions from Kalman Filter is causing issues.

Comment: If you are using [this](https://github.com/jvirico/kalman-tracker), it comes with full source code.  You could determine why things are not correct by debugging the code.

Comment: I am using [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d6a/classcv_1_1KalmanFilter.html)

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable. You need to at least provide some [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with example input data. This instability in your figures can come from anything, bug in your code, system being generally unstable etc.

Comment: I have updated the question and added more details. Please have a look